# Facebook messenger chatbot working only for me but not for other users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-chat, facebook-chatbot

I am having strange issue after i created facebook messenger chatbot app using [pimax](https://github.com/pimax/fb-messenger-php) implementation and i followed all steps and created facebook page for the app called [MiTaxi](https://www.facebook.com/MiTaxiApp/) i found that it works only for me! but when i test my app using any other facebook users by the way my app is a live

[image]

[image]

I am not sure what is worng the application work prefect but no one else can test it but me.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while using Azure Bot Services for one of my FB Page. It works only for me and not made public.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you did not go through the review process yet? Here´s the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review

Withour review, it will only work for users with a role in the App.

Answer (score 2):

Your messenger bot needs to be formally approved by Facebook.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review

The images you linked are for your app as a whole, which is live. You need to get specifically the messenger bot approved.

Until then, you can add specific people as testers who will have access to the bot, pre-approval. This can be done under the roles section.